# Deserialize axios response based on the generic type

Tags: typescript

In my code, I'm using [axios-case-converter](https://github.com/mpyw/axios-case-converter) for the automatic snake -> camel case conversion. Also, I have the endpoint that returns JSON or text based on the requested mime type. I need to be able to deserialize or keep it as a string based on the generic and the mime type.

The code is supposed to look something like this:

```
type Format = 'json' | 'text';
interface MyType {}

const get = <
              T extends string | MyType = string,
              TFormat extends Format = 'json',
              // If TFormat = 'json' + T = MyType => MyType
              // T = string => string
              TOutput = T extends MyType
                ? (TFormat extends 'json' : never)
                : string,
              TDeserialize = TOutput extends MyType ? true : false
            >(format: TFormat, deserialize?: TDeserialize) => {
  return axios.get<TOutput>('<url>', transformResponse: res => {
    if (!deserialize) return res;
    return axios.defaults.transformResponse;
  });
}
```

Is there any way to write it more human-readable?

Comment: Why not make `get` take a parameter like `shouldDeserialize` that makes it decide what to do with it?

Comment: Ideally, I want to have a type-safe approach. if I want a `string` it should not deserialize, etc. Also, I'm trying to understand how to run the transformers-chain from the code

Comment: @kellys I think your idea might work if I can specify multiple conditions in the generic (updated the question)